# Generation straight line scatter chart in POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Im trying to create scatter chart with apache poi. but im getting soft lines and so many values on y axis that it looks like black stripe
here is my code. Where is my problem? Is it possible to generate such chart in poi?

```
    XSSFDrawing xlsx_drawing = my_worksheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    XSSFClientAnchor anchor = xlsx_drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, x1, y1, x2, y2);
    /* Create the chart object based on the anchor point */
    XSSFChart my_line_chart = xlsx_drawing.createChart(anchor);

    CTChart ctChart = my_line_chart.getCTChart();
    CTTitle title = ctChart.addNewTitle();
    CTTx tx = title.addNewTx();
    CTTextBody rich = tx.addNewRich();
    rich.addNewBodyPr();  // body properties must exist, but can be empty
    CTTextParagraph para = rich.addNewP();
    CTRegularTextRun r = para.addNewR();
    r.setT(name)
    XSSFChartLegend legend = my_line_chart.getOrCreateLegend();
    legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.RIGHT);     
    ScatterChartData data = my_line_chart.getChartDataFactory().createScatterChartData();     
    ChartAxis bottomAxis = my_line_chart.getChartAxisFactory().createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    XSSFValueAxis leftAxis = my_line_chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
    leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);     
    ChartDataSource<Number> xs = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(my_worksheet, new CellRangeAddress(titlesRow+1, columns, xrow, xrow));
    for(String key: yrow.keySet()){
        ChartDataSource<Number> ys1 = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(my_worksheet, new CellRangeAddress(titlesRow+1, columns, yrow.get(key), yrow.get(key)));
        ScatterChartSeries chartSerie = data.addSerie(xs, ys1);
        chartSerie.setTitle(key);
    }
    /* Plot the chart with the inputs from data and chart axis */
    my_line_chart.plot(data, new ChartAxis[] { bottomAxis, leftAxis });
```

Answer (score 0):

So i found out, that to add chart with straight lines i should add code

```
  for(CTScatterSer s : my_line_chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getScatterChartArray(0).getSerArray()){
        s.addNewMarker().addNewSymbol().setVal(STMarkerStyle.NONE);
        s.addNewSmooth().setVal(false);
    }
```

Comment: where in your code did you place what you wrote in here?